# Uniform convergence of integral function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

Let $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{K}(\mathbb{R})$ be a smooth function with compact support and $t \geq0$. Then

$
g_{t}(x) =\frac{1}{t}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f(x+\sqrt{t}z)-f(x)-\frac{t}{2}f^{''}(x))e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}dz \rightarrow 0
$ uniformly
for $t \rightarrow 0$ holds.

I am really struggling to show this and would be grateful for hints or a solution.

Comment: Have you tried using a Taylor expansion for $f$?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't get anything useful.

Comment: Is this copied correctly? For $f(x)=x$ it doesn't hold.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the function should also have compact support.

Comment: $tz^{2}$ or just $t$ for the coefficient of $f''(x)$?

Comment: The coefficient is $\frac{t}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\eta_{x,t,z}$ be such that
\begin{align*}
f(x+\sqrt{t}z)=f(x)+\sqrt{t}zf'(x)+\dfrac{tz^{2}}{2}f''(x)+\dfrac{t\sqrt{t}z^{3}}{6}f^{(3)}(\eta_{x,t,z}).
\end{align*}
Note that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}ze^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz=0$, so we obtain that
\begin{align*}
g_{t}(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}f''(x)\int_{\mathbb{R}}(z^{2}-1)e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz+\dfrac{\sqrt{t}}{6}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f^{(3)}(\eta_{x,t,z})z^{3}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\left|g_{t}(x)-\dfrac{1}{2}f''(x)\int_{\mathbb{R}}(z^{2}-1)e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz\right|\leq\dfrac{\sqrt{t}\cdot\max|f^{(3)}|}{6}\cdot\int_{\mathbb{R}}|z|^{3}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
uniformly in $x$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.

I do not see why the term $\frac{1}{2}f''(x)\int_{\mathbb{R}}(z^{2}-1)e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz$ has to be vanished.

Comment: This vanishes because $\int_{\mathbb{R}}z^{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}=1$ holds, as this is the variance of a standard normal distribution.

Comment: Oh I see, then I have solved your question in some sense.

Comment: That helped me a lot-thank you!