# Uniform convergence of integral functions-2

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

Let $f \in \mathcal{C}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $f''$ exists and $f'' \in \mathcal{C}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ and $t \geq0$. Then

$
g_{t}(x) =\frac{1}{t}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f(x+\sqrt{t}z)-f(x)-\frac{t}{2}f^{''}(x))e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}dz \rightarrow 0
$ uniformly
for $t \rightarrow 0$ holds.

One sees the pointwise convergence with Taylor expansion for $f$ but I don't know how to show the uniform convergence. Here [Uniform convergence of integral function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123520/uniform-convergence-of-integral-function) is the solution to the assertion with stronger assumptions. Sorry for the questions being so similar.

I would be grateful for hints or a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have from Taylor's Theorem,
\begin{align*}
f(x+\sqrt{t}z)=f(x)+\sqrt{t}zf'(x)+\dfrac{tz^{2}}{2}f''(x)+tz^2R(x,\sqrt{t}z)
\end{align*} where $R(x,h)=\int_0^1(1-t)(f''(x+th)-f''(x))dt$.
Note that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}ze^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz=0$, so we obtain that
\begin{align*}
g_{t}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}R(x,\sqrt{t}z)z^{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz.
\end{align*}
$R(x,h)$ is uniformly continuous in $(x,h)$ for bounded $h$ as $f''$ vanishes at infinity. As $R(x,0)=0$ we thus have for $h<\delta, R(x,h)<\epsilon$. Also we have that $R(x,h)\leq \max(|{f''}|)$ Putting all this together we can bound $g_t(x)$ as follows,
\begin{align*}
|g_{t}(x)|\leq \max{|f''|}\int_{|z|\geq\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{t}}}z^{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz+\epsilon\int_{|z|<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{t}}}z^{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2}}dz
\end{align*}
This bound is independent of $x$ and approaches $\epsilon$ as $t\to 0$

Comment: Some of this work is based of the question you link.

Comment: Why does $f''$ have compact support? Do we not only know $f'' \in \mathcal{C}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: I have seen that notation used as compact support, so what are you using it for? Vanish at infinity? If so proof should still work with mild adjustments.

Comment: I use this for vanishing at infinity but I see, it works anyway. One more question: Do you have some link where I can find this formula $R(x,h)=\int_0^1(1-t)(f''(x+th))dt$ for the remainder?

Comment: You are missing the $-f''(x)$. And my best reference is Abraham & Robbin's Transversal mapping and flows.